# Change Linux Time to trick System Uptime

Tags: linux, datetime

I'm trying to test a software out, and I need to have a server uptime at 100 days. My current server uptime is 3 hours. I changed the system time using the following command

```
date -s "27 Feb 2015 12:00:00"
```

and then used the Date command to verify the time had changed:

```
Fri Feb 27 12:08:40 CDT 2015
```

but when I type Uptime it still shows

```
 12:00:51 up  3:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.03, 0.06, 0.05
```

is there a way to get the uptime to actually change other than wait until Feb of next year?

Answer (score 0):

Just backup and replace `/usr/bin/uptime` with your own script which will show 100 days uptime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UptimeFaker to change the machines up time for your testing.

http://www.etheus.net/UptimeFaker

Note : Make sure that you have followed the steps correctly as described in the link